# Derivative as a rate of change

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Could someone please help explain this answer to me?

The question is:

The equations for free fall at surfaces of Mars and Jupiter ($s$ in meters, $t$ in seconds) are $s$ = $1.86t^2$ on Mars and $s$ = $11.44t^2$ on Jupiter. How long does it take a rock falling from rest to reach a velocity of 27.8 m/sec (about 100km/h) on each planet?

Comment: Where did you get this question? This is the worst violation of proper handling of units that I've ever seen. This shouldn't be in any books, it teaches bad practice and spits in the face of physics.

Comment: @orion I was cringing and wincing throughout my writing of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact $v = \frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\mathrm{d}t}$, that is, velocity is the rate of change of displacement, then for

**Mars:** We have $$v_{\text{mars}} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(1.86t^2) = 3.72t$$ So that $$v_{\text{mars}} = 27.8 \iff 27.8 = 3.72t \iff t = \frac{27.8}{3.72}$$

Can you do the same for the other planet? I'll start it off for you:

**Jupiter:** We have $$v_{\text{jupiter}} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(11.44t^2) = \cdots$$

Comment: Therefore Jupiter would then be 22.88? I think I am missing how 37.8 was found.

Comment: You have $27.8 = 22.88t$, correct, now solve for $t$ to get the time.

Comment: @Ducksauce88, my sincerest apologies, that was a typo on my part! I edited the answer to use the correct value.

Comment: I literally figured that out right before you commented. Thanks for this, my pearson book is the absolute worst!!!

Comment: Haha, good luck with it! Glad I helped. :-)

Comment: And just to finish, the answer would be ${t=27.8/22.88}$ after dividing both sides by 22.88

Comment: Correct! Good job. :-)  You would put that in a calculator, and round to 3 s.f normally, I just didn't have a calculator with me and my mental arithmetic isn't good. xD
Feel free to mark this answer as accepted by clicking the tick on the left if you feel this answered your question.